# Python: Class object returns TypeError

Tags: python, class

seed and n are itegers. in the output i have `TypeError: <__main__._rundckdo.<locals>.createDie.<locals>.Die object at .0x2b1a1e567630> is not JSON serializable` .How can i fix this without using json library? what i am doing wrong?

```
def createDie(seed, n):
  class Die(object):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.seed = args[0]
        self.n = args[1]
    def __bool__(self):
        return True if self.seed>self.n else False

  class Game(object):
    die = Die(seed, n)

  return Game.die
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)

Comment: i can't import other library

Comment: What is the intended output of the `createDie()` function?

Comment: for seed=2 n =1: output True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098797/python-class-object-returns-typeerror#comment79160400_46098797), you expect `createDie()` to return a boolean value. As it is, it's returning an instance of the `Die` class. This is causing the `TypeError` since the caller doesn't know how to serialize it.

You'll need to explicitly get the boolean value:

```
return bool(Game.die)
```

Comment: and what to do if i need to return integer instead of returning object

Comment: @AvoAsatryan The same way you did the boolean: create an `__int__()` method on the class that returns an integer, and end your function with `return int(Game.die)`

Comment: in this task i can't change return Game.die. in this case how i need to return int type?

Comment: I suppose you could move the `int()` up into the `Game` class definition: `die = int(Die(seed, n))`

Comment: no, i cant, i only can change the body of Die class

Comment: Either make `Die` a function instead of a class, or if you can't do that, make `Die` inherit from `int`, which is way out of the scope of this question.